# Pressing Tab in conemu + Python3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to ConEmu, so please forgive me if this is too simple. When I press Tab key (say trying to define a function), ConEmu will show many keywords but not a simple "tab", is there someway to disable this? I checked keyboard settings, but couldn't find solution.

Thanks!

[image: After tab pressed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConEmu does not handle tab key at all. What you see is the python auto completion. Refer to python manuals or forums...